# Concatenating the contents of two files from the second row onwards

Tags: awk

How to concatenate two files one to another using `awk` so that the first line of both is ignored?

Each file is in format:

```
#filename
4 5
5 6
```

Second for instance

```
#filename
7 6 
1 4
```

Expected output:

```
4 5 
5 6 
7 6 
1 4
```

Comment: welcome to U&L, what's wrong with `cat` ? e.g. `cat f1 f2`

Comment: What is the logic here? Is it just file 1 followed by file 2?

Comment: @Archemar Just concatenating with `cat` would leave the header in the output.

Comment: @Kusalananda my bad, was early morning, I didn't see the catch.

Answer (score 2):

It looks as if you want to concatenate the contents of the two files while skipping the first row of each file.

Getting everything but the first row of a file can be done in many ways, for example using `awk`:

```
awk 'FNR > 1' file
```

With `awk`, it's actually quite easy to do what you'd want to do with that exact `awk` program:

```
$ awk 'FNR > 1' file1 file2
4 5
5 6
7 6
1 4
```

`FNR` is a variable that `awk` maintains that holds the current record number (line number by default) in the current file.  If `FNR` in this program is strictly greater than 1, then the current line in the current file is not the first line of that file.  A program with just a condition like this in it will cause the lines for which the condition is true to be printed.

Answer (score 2):

For completeness, here's a GNU `tail`-based solution

```
tail -q -n +2 file1 file2
```

Answer (score 0):

Using sed i have done by below method

```
sed -n -e '1!p' f1 ;sed -n -e '1!p' f2
```

output

```
4 5
5 6
7 6
1 4
```

Answer (score -1):

Why not

```
awk '{print $0}' file1 file2
```

Comment: ... `so that the first line of both is ignored`...